# Why does DROP TABLE-ing the `wp_options` reset my user session?

Tags: sql, core

If I do:

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query("DELETE FROM wp_options");
```

Suddenly, I'm logged out. But how come? I thought all sessions are kept locally, surely, a reference to my session must be present on the server, but how can I avoid this issue?

I want to wipe the entire table, just not these things related to the user sessions, as such, I identified certain possible keys that should be kept, but with no success:

```
logged_in_key
logged_in_salt
auth_key
auth_salt
```

What could be the issue here?

Comment: I recommend you to read this great article about wp_options table. https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/wp-options-autoloaded-data/#settings_saved

Comment: Why would someone delete the complete wp_options table?

Comment: Dropping/clearing the wp-options table could break a lot of things. Plugins/themes store stuff in the wp-options table. As does WP, even on a newly created site.So you should be careful doing that. I'd even say that you shouldn't do that. Well-behaved plugins/theme will delete their items from the wp-options table when they are deleted. Although some will not, and it's not a big deal (IMHO) if they don't remove their stuff.The size of the wp-options table doesn't really affect the overall speed of the site, in most cases.